# If $h(n) = 9n - 11$ and $g(n) = n^2 - 9$, what is $(g \circ h)(n + 5)$?

Tags: functions

How do you solve this?
\begin{align*}
h(n) & = 9n-11\\
g(n) & = n^2 - 9
\end{align*}
Find $(g \circ h)(n+5)$.

Comment: To square something: ```$n^2$``` or ```$(n+m)^2$```

Comment: function composition: ```$g \circ h$```

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site. When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  For instance, do you know how to find $h(n + 5)$?

Answer (score 0):

If by $(g\ \circ\ h)(x)$ you mean $g(h(x))$, then $g(h(x)) = h^2(x)-9 = (9x - 11)^2 -9=(81x^2 - 198x + 121) - 9 = 81x^2 - 198x + 112$, so $(g \circ h)(n+5) = 81(n+5)^2 - 198(n+5) +112 = 81n^2 + 810n + 2025 -198n + 990 + 112 = 81n^2 +612n + 3127$.
Hope I well understood your question...